# ERROR (com.facebook.sdk error 5.) in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my project i am not posting anything only fetching different data from FaceBook.

some times i am getting the data but
most of the time i am getting this Error

**The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)**

my small code is

```
permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"user_friends",@"read_stream",
@"read_requests",@"user_birthday",@"user_about_me",@"user_hometown",
@"user_location",@"user_likes",@"email",
               nil];


[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:
 ^(FBSession *session,
   FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
NSString *queryNew55 = @"SELECT post_id,fromid,time FROM comment WHERE time > 1375553100 AND post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id = me())";

     // Set up the query parameter
     NSDictionary *queryParam15 = @{ @"q": queryNew55 };
     // Make the API request that uses FQL
     [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                                  parameters:queryParam15
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                           completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                               id result,
                                               NSError *error) {
                               if (error) {
                                   NSLog(@"Error in comment query");
                                   NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                               } else {

                                   NSLog(@"comments Result: %@", result);


                               }

                           }
      ];

 }];
```

I seen lots of thing on google on the same Error
and i applied that too but nothings works permanently.

in FaceBook App All the things like sandbox mode is off and bundle id are set perfectly.

any help like link or code or any thing related to this will be great Help.

Comment: Sam, have you tried adding "basic_info" into your permissions?  I remember reading somewhere that you must get that permission first and foremost...

Comment: @VineeshTP where i can get your answer buddy ?

Comment: @VineeshTP I mean, can you please link your answer here...

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but my answer might help some other people.

I was getting this error after following some of their code/tutorials/documentation.

It seems there is a disconnect between their documentation and some of the sample code.

using

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.state != FBSessionStateCreated) {
        // Create a new, logged out session.
        self.facebookSession = [[FBSession alloc] init];
    }
```

and

```
[self.facebookSession openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                     FBSessionState status,
                                                     NSError *error) {
```

will not result in the session being updated in

```
FBSession.activeSession
```

getting updated.

So you will have a session that is open (self.facebookSession) and a session that is crated&TokenLoaded - which is not open.

So making any calls like:

```
[FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
```

will fail as the FBRequestConnection uses FBSession.activeSession

So in the completion handler you can see the active session if you are going to manage the session your self.

```
[self.facebookSession openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                     FBSessionState status,
                                                     NSError *error) {

        [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
        // post or load user data.
    }];
```

It seems to work for me now,

hope this helps